# Quaternion - calibration sensor

Tags: geometry, rotations, quaternions, orientation

I have attached my sensor to a box. What I am interested in is the rotation of the box with respect to the world. In my case, to avoid the gimball lock, and beacause the sensor already provides it, I am using a quaternion.

The relation between the orientation I am interested in, and the output of the sensor is the following:

$$q_{sensor/world} = q_{sensor/box} \cdot q_{box/world}$$

I know that my sensor is not perfectly aligned, hence the $$q_{sensor/box}$$ term is not a unit vector, but an unknown.
If I want to compute the orientation of the box with respect to the world, what is the best approach to do it ?

Comment: Well, if you know $q_{sensor/box}$ then quaternions are invertible so $$q_{box/world} = q_{sensor/box}^{-1}q_{sensor/world}$$. If these are unit quaternions (which they ought to be) then the inverse is just the conjugate.

Comment: The point is I don't know $$q_{sensor/box}$$, hence my question for suggestions to determine it. 
I acknowledge my question was not very clear

Comment: You're going to have to do some calibration then. Setup an experiment in such a way that you know exactly what the $box/world$ orientation is and calculate $q_{box/world}$ from this; combine this with the corresponding $q_{sensor/world}$ reading to get $q_{sensor/box} = q_{sensor/world}q_{box/world}^{-1}$. Since you'll probably want to do this experiment several times, keep in mind that $\pm q$ both represent the same rotation; it would probably be easiest to combat this by e.g. negating whatever you get for $q_{sensor/box}$ as appropriate so that its scalar part is always positive.

Comment: Thank you. Just a remark, why do you say that +- q is the same rotation ? And what does it matter in my case? I will not have to sum up quaternions

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer because there were some points I wanted to expand on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to do some calibration. Setup an experiment in such a way that you know exactly what the $box/world$ orientation is and calculate $q_{box/world}$ from this; combine this with the corresponding $q_{sensor/world}$ reading to get $q_{sensor/box}=q_{sensor/world}q_{box/world}^{-1}$.

If we represent a vector $v$ as an imaginary quaterion then its rotation via another quaternion $q$ is $v \mapsto qvq^{-1}$. If we replace $q$ with $-q$ we get the same rotation. When you take two measurements $q_1, q_2$ of $q_{sensor/box}$ and want to average them, then it might end up that this average is nearly zero because we ended up with $q_1 \approx -q_2$. The simplest way to combat this is to check a component of $q_1$ and $q_2$ and replace e.g. $q_2$ with $-q_2$ if the sign of this component differs in $q_1, q_2$. If the component is you check is zero or close to zero, then you should choose a different component.

Now a note on averaging. You could take your measurements $q_1, q_2,\dotsc q_k$, form $q = q_1 + q_2 + \dotsb q_k$, and then maybe normalize this to $q/|q|$ where of course $|q| = \sqrt{q\bar q}$. It is better practice however to average their *logarithms* since this keeps everything in "rotation space" (though you may still prefer the naieve averaging because the calculation is simpler). What I mean is that every rotation quaternion $q$ can be written
$$
  q = e^{\theta v/2}
$$
where $v$ is a purely imaginary unit quaternion representing the axis of rotation and $\theta$ is the angle of rotation about this axis. So if $q_i = e^{\theta_i v_i/2}$, it better to form their "average" as
$$
  q = \exp\frac1k\sum_{i=1}\frac{\theta_i v_i}2.
$$
We can do this as follows: for simplicity, normalize the signs of $q_1,\dotsc,q_k$ as described above. Then since Euler's formula applies
$$
  q_i = e^{\theta_iv_i/2} = \cos\theta_i/2 + v_i\sin\theta_i/2
$$
and if $q_i = q_{iw} + q_{ix}i + q_{iy}j + q_{iz}k$ then that means
$$
  \theta_i/2 = \arctan\frac{\sqrt{q_{ix}^2 + q_{iy}^2 + q_{iz}^2}}{q_{iw}},\quad v_i = \frac{q_{ix}i + q_{iy}j + q_{iz}k}{\sqrt{q_{ix}^2 + q_{iy}^2 + q_{iz}^2}}.
$$
If preferred, we can also write this in terms of just $q_i$:
$$
  \theta_i/2 = \arctan\frac{|q_i - \bar q_i|}{q_i + \bar q_i},\quad
  v_i = \frac{q_i - \bar q_i}{|q_i - \bar q_i|}.
$$
Now let $V$ be the average of these quantities:
$$
  V = \frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\theta_i}2v_i.
$$
Then the "average" quaternion $q$ is
$$
  q = \cos|V| + \frac V{|V|}\sin|V|
$$

Comment: Thank you by the way for your answer